# Is there a JQuery plugin that turns radio buttons into nice vertical selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Transform traditional radio buttons into a list (vertically), and then make it nice looking?

I know there is JQuery UI's radio buttons, but they are more better suited horizontally, and they are not very good looking.

Comment: Good looking is really subjective.  Whats to stop radio buttons being in a vertical list now with a bit of CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery mobile might help.  Have a look at the following

http://jquerymobile.com/

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html

You will still have to have a fallback style for certain browsers.